# Why are my \n not working in PHP?

Tags: php, sax

I'm playing with SAX and noticed it's not line breaking properly. I have no iea why.

```
function flush_data() {

    global $level, $char_data;

    $char_data = trim($char_data);

    if( strlen( $char_data ) > 0 ) {

        print "\n";


        $data = split("\n", wordwrap($char_data, 76 - ($level*2)));
        foreach($data as $line) {
            print str_repeat(' ', ($level +1)) . "[".$line."]"."\n";
        }
    }

    $char_data = '';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can try

```
print PHP_EOL;
```

It almost goes without saying, if you're doing this in a web page you need

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

`\r\n` is incorrect, `PHP_EOL` is the correct way to get a platform-independent newline.

Comment: It was the content type part. Thanks!

Comment: `PHP_EOL` is platform dependent, not independent.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
\r\n
```

return and new line feed work different on a windows and linux machine.

Answer (score -2):

I am an absolute beginner so I have no idea why 
 worked when I tried to solve a similar problem in my VERY simply php script. Give it a try. My code:

```
    $myfavmovie = urlencode("Life of Brian"); 
echo "Welcome back {$_SESSION['username']}";
echo "<br>";
echo "<a href='userseggs.php?favmovie=$myfavmovie'>
        Click here to see information about the eggs in your incubator"; 
echo "</a>";
```

Using any other newline tag/character didn't work. Hope it helps.

Comment: Adding newlines in html just changes the source, the browser doesnt render them.